# XGetImage with pre-allocated memory buffer

Tags: c, x11, xlib

Now I am dealing with some Xlib programming and want to take screenshots frequently and efficiently.

It seems that [`XGetImage`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html) internally allocates memory buffer for an image.
I want to use pre-allocated memory buffer in order to avoid massive memory allocation. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `XGetSubImage` it works with previously defined XImage and this way you can reuse the image.

Comment: [XGetSubImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetSubImage.html) takes `dest_image`.

Comment: that's simply wrong. XGetSubImage create a new XImage with new allocated memory and copies specified data from this new XImage to the refered XImage (dest_image).

See: https://github.com/sulmone/X11/blob/master/libX11-1.5.0/src/GetImage.c

Comment: so.. for completeness:  in this case you can reuse the image data from refered image - but you don't get rid of massive memory allocation... .